# What's the svn revert equivalent in git?

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to find the equivalent of `svn Revert` in Git. In `svn`, when I rigth-click a file then click `revert`, that will undo all the local edits. the file goes back to the last `commit`. I can't find the exact same command in Git. Since I'm new, I don't want to mess-up my work.

Let say I made a commit **Init**. Then I made some changes. Now I'd like to go back to the **Init** state.

Thanks for helping

Comment: tl;dr: git checkout

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because of the staging area, it's not quite as simple as an `svn revert`.  Depending on what you've done, and what your goal is, you need to use either `git checkout` or `git reset`.  You need to be careful with `git reset` though, as you can re-write history and lose work.

Let's say you have the commit graph:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D
```

And you're currently at `D` with some changes.  To simply discard all changes (staged or not), you can use `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git reset --hard D`.  Both will reset the state of your working copy.

If you want the state of your working copy to be identical to `A`, but not lose commits `B` and `C`, then you should use: `git checkout A -- .` from the top of your working copy.  That'll set the state of your working copy to the contents of `A`.  At this point, your working tree is dirty, so you'll need to commit to record the fact that you wanted to go back.  The commit graph at this point would be:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- A'
```

Where `A'` is a new commit (with a different id) that brings your work back to the equivalent of commit `A`.

If you want to lose commit `B` and `C`, you can use `git reset --hard A`.  This will move your branch pointer back to commit `A`.  You are now re-writing history, so be careful.  If you're working with other team members on this branch, you don't want to do this.  If it's your own branch, you likely need to use `git push -f`, where the `-f` stands for `--force`, when pushing it to your remote repo.  You also need to make sure that you've set `push.default` to either `current` or `upstream` to avoid pushing all matching branches and accidentally rewinding someone's work.

FWIW, I wrote up a [blog post about reverting changes in Git](http://www.szakmeister.net/blog/2011/oct/12/reverting-changes-git/) several years ago.  It's still relevant today.  You may find it useful.

Answer (score 18):

As long as the files are not staged I usually use

```
git checkout -- .
```

You can also use

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/some/file.txt
```

to checkout a single file from `HEAD`, or any other commit

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard Init
```

Will get your `HEAD` back to `Init`.  You may want to make a branch or tag first, to save whatever other work you'd done.

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'Init': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: `Init` is the name of a specific commit in OP's question. Replace with the hash you care about for your own use case.